# Microsoft Graph API accessing Excel doc permissions

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I am diving into the Microsoft Graph API and want to use its features to interact with an Excel workbook. I intend to create a client side application that interfaces with my API which in turn interfaces with Microsoft Graph API.

I ran into some confusion with the [Microsoft Graph permission](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) documentation. When sifting through the Excel API documentation, I saw that in order to `Update Range` or `Get Worksheet` (or really any endpoint) I need to have `Delegated (work or school account)` permission. I then looked at the Graph permission doc mentioned above and it says:

> Delegated permissions are used by apps that have a signed-in user present. For these apps either the user or an administrator consents to the permissions that the app requests and the app is delegated permission to act as the signed-in user when making calls to Microsoft Graph. Some delegated permissions can be consented to by non-administrative users, but some higher-privileged permissions require administrator consent.

To me, this reads "a user must login using oauth to interact with a workbook via the API". I'm hoping that is not the case, because I want to have the workbook data publicly available and to have read/write permission. I understand I will have to authenticate *some* (admin) user within my organization in order to retrieve/update a workbook (via the Graph API) stored in OneDrive, for example, but I just wanted to see the requirements for accessing the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you intend to use Excel workbook as a central source data rather than an individual user based store. In that case you can access API without a user sign-in by using application level consent. See [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service). Client "app" will call into a server (such as nodeJs) and that in-turn will make API calls to Microsoft Graph to interact with Excel workbook. This server-to-Graph call is abstracted from the client app and hence secure.

The downside of this approach is that you'll need server implementation and you can't implement single page application that doesn't require server side implementation. It is not a big hurdle - just takes different set-up.

Comment: Makes sense about the application level permissions, but what is throwing me off is when looking at the Excel Graph API docs it says `Application level permission is not supported`. For example [Get Worksheet](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/worksheet_get).

Comment: I believe it does support. This I think is a documentation mistake. I'll get back to you. If this doesn't work - you could also use delegated permission. It is bit odd in that case as all updates seems to come from one person and initial authorization and token caching has to be done manually in the beginning.